# How to exclude the entire result of a Grouped row based on a value of any of the rows it contains

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
 ID | Class | Item
 ---+-------+------
 1  | 1     | 1
 2  | 1     | 2
 3  | 2     | 1
 4  | 2     | 3
 5  | 3     | 2
```

and a query that looks something like this:

```
Select Class, MAX(Item) FROM myTable WHERE Item <> 3 GROUP BY Class
```

This results in:

```
  Class | Item
 -------+------
  1     | 2
  2     | 1
  3     | 2
```

However I want to exclude all results where a Class contains an Item with the value of 3, not just rows that are 3 so it should return:

```
  Class | Item
 -------+------
  1     | 2
  3     | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Select Class, MAX(Item) 
FROM myTable 
WHERE class not in (
         select class from #demo where item  = 3
                    ) 
GROUP BY Class
```